# How to open a message database(.db) file from Sony Xperia phone in computer?

Tags: sms, data-transfer

So I had backed up my files and messages from sony xperia phone and saved all files in the computer....

Now I need to open the messages file in the backup folder which has the format of .bk...

I tried to use 7 zip to extract the .db file...

**But when I opened the .db file in Notepad it appeared haphazardly with many characters and the messages were there but were jumbled in between the characters...**

**So I want to view them in a proper format..... Any suggestion or advice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.db` files are not plain-text files, so Notepad is the wrong approach. Those are [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) databases, so you will have to use some SQLite browser for the task. The linked Wiki page gives you some more details. [SQLiteman](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/) would be a good choice, and there's even [a portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqliteman-portable) available. For an alternative, there's also [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Comment: I tried SQLite but i dont know how to handle it.....

Comment: I mean to say I opened the file in the software but there were so many options like tables,indices,triggers ...etc which I could not understand anyhting about......I need to view the message part from it.....if that is relevant

Comment: @IshanTaneja We can't teach SQL here since that is obviously off topic. Izzy explained as much as he can explain while staying on topic. Search internet for more relevant information about `.db` files and database browsers.

Comment: @SarpSTA Ok then............but I was hoping for a more organised user friendly gui.....

Comment: @IshanTaneja browse the tables, that's where the data is. Ignore the rest. You'll have to do some digging on your own, we cannot tell how to extract the messages. I don't even know whether those are stored "in one piece", or spread across multiple tables/columns/rows: each application handles that in its own way.

Comment: Anytime – always glad to help!